# Multidimensional K-Means wiith sklearn, centroids problem when plotting

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I am working with a dataset (X) to predict 12 clusters with K-Means using python SKLEARN library:

```
numClusters= 12
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=numClusters).fit(X)
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_

# Predicting the clusters
labels = kmeans.predict(X)
# Getting the cluster centers
C = kmeans.cluster_centers_

#transform n variiables to 2 principal components to plot
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(X)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents
         , columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2'])

colors =['red','green','blue','cyan','yellow', 'lime','orange','coral','brown','peru','khaki','tan']
centroidColor= []
for item in range(numClusters):
  centroidColor.append(colors[item])

dataPointColor=[]
for row in labels:
  dataPointColor.append(colors[row])

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
ax.set_xlabel('Principal Component 1', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Principal Component 2', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title('2 component PCA', fontsize = 20)
plt.scatter(principalDf['principal component 1'], principalDf['principal component 2'], 
c=dataPointColor, s=50, alpha=0.5)

plt.scatter(C[:, 0], C[:, 1], c=centroidColor, s=200, marker=('x'))
plt.show()
```

My problem comes when trying to plot the n dimensions of my dataset into 2 PCA. The clustering seems fine, but the centroids (**marked with a star icon**) are not correct:

[image]

The centroids should not always be in the same near spot.
I know that I did not standardize the dataset (X) because all values are in a range [1:5]:

```
[[4 5 4 ... 4 4 4]
[4 4 1 ... 4 3 5]
[3 4 3 ... 1 1 4]
...
[2 5 1 ... 2 1 4]
[5 5 1 ... 5 5 1]
[2 5 1 ... 1 1 5]]
```

Could the problem come from that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plot you used PCA to reduce the dimensionality of your data, but you plotted the first 2 dimensions of your centroids. You should also transform the centroids using the PCA transform you fitted on your data.

This code should work for you

```
numClusters= 12
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=numClusters).fit(X)
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_

# Predicting the clusters
labels = kmeans.predict(X)
# Getting the cluster centers
C = kmeans.cluster_centers_

#transform n variiables to 2 principal components to plot
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca_fit = pca.fit(X)
principalComponents = pca_fit.transform(X)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = principalComponents
         , columns = ['principal component 1', 'principal component 2'])

colors =['red','green','blue','cyan','yellow', 'lime','orange','coral','brown','peru','khaki','tan']
centroidColor= []
for item in range(numClusters):
  centroidColor.append(colors[item])

dataPointColor=[]
for row in labels:
  dataPointColor.append(colors[row])

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
ax.set_xlabel('Principal Component 1', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Principal Component 2', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title('2 component PCA', fontsize = 20)
plt.scatter(principalDf['principal component 1'], principalDf['principal component 2'], 
c=dataPointColor, s=50, alpha=0.5)

C_transformed = pca_fit.transform(C)
plt.scatter(C_transformed[:, 0], C_transformed[:, 1], c=centroidColor, s=200, marker=('x'))
plt.show()
```

Comment: yes, that was the problem. Thanks!